# How to distinguish between two StartActivityFor Result()

Tags: android

I have two listeners

```
fromCityTrain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),train_autocomplete.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 2);
        }
    });

    toCityTrain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),train_autocomplete.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 3);
        }
    });
```

Both are going to same activity. Now when I return back data how will I know which one has called it.

This is the content in train_autocomplete.class

```
Intent intent=new Intent();

            intent.putExtra("stationCode",stationCode);
            intent.putExtra("stationName",stationName);
            setResult(2,intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: Use the request's code to distinguish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onActivityResult` will provide you `requestCode`. In your example it will be 2 for the first case and 3 for the 2nd case

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 2:
        // fromCityTrain
        if(resultCode==2) Log.i("TAG", "resultCode 2 returned from activity");
        else Log.i("TAG", "resultCode "+ resultCode +" returned from activity");
        break;
    case 3:
        // toCityTrain
        if(resultCode==2) Log.i("TAG", "resultCode 2 returned from activity");
        else Log.i("TAG", "resultCode "+ resultCode +" returned from activity");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: before finish(); I used setResult(2,intent); This will set the request code as 2 everytime no matter who called it and if I use 3 then everytime 3 request code will be passed

Comment: I think you are confused between requestCode and resultCode. setResult will set the resultCode and not requestCode.

Comment: Oh got it....But still both result code gets send no matter who calls it.